# Would it save gas to save an array as a comma-separated string in a smart contract if I need to then access its elements?

Tags: solidity

If I saved an array as

```
string values = "[123,456,789,356,234,325....]" //256 elements
```

instead of as a normal array of uints, and then created a loop in which to access each element delimited by the comma, would I avoid paying 20k gas for each of those elements? Or would it count as storing a new variable each iteration of the loop? If it would work, what type of storage should I save those variable as?